# How to send concurrent request in jmeter as browser does?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am doing load testing in jmeter. I have recorded the script using jmeter recording of my application. When i am running the script then response time is greater than the response time comes in browser.
I have used the concurrent pool in Http Request Header but its not working for me because i have different http requests. 
So Is there any way that we can send the parellel http requests of Sampler for same user.

**Please help! Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Try "clean" browser session - delete all cookies, cache, etc. - response times will stop being different - all you need is just to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan

If it doesn't help - it may be [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). JMeter doesn't have built-in mechanisms for simulating AJAX requests so it needs to be worked around.

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for different options highlighted and explained.